# jssor with Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, jssor

I'm developping a web site with Angular 2.

At this time I have purchased the subscription to Jssor to generate image slider for more than 3 separated sliders running into same page.

My current issue is with a dinamic slider that is generated after document load, it isn't shown.

I have found jssorslider in npmjs.com, but it's one year older.

Have you on hand a current jssor for Angular 2 or some helping doc for implementing it?

Thank you

Mario Ochoa

Comment: To initialize jssor slider, it requires html code. Angular helps to render html code dynamically. Please make sure html code has been rendered property before the statement like ```jssor_1_slider_init();```.

Comment: Hi, I have read that kind of procedure... but in my case, the second image slider is rendered after `jssor_1_slider_init()`... as it's generated dynamically by a secondary Angular Component... In this case, how can I call jssor to initialize the secondary dynamical image slider?

Comment: augular_render_1();jssor_1_slider_init();angular_render_2();jssor_2_slider_init();

Comment: Note that angular and jssor slider do different jobs on you page. 1. angular generate html code. 2. jssor slider initializes with html code.

Comment: jssor slider works after rendering of angular. Is that clear?

Comment: thank you, I'll make it tomorrow

Comment: @jssor  see my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

Brother I recently used Jssor, successfully, with Angular 2.

In your `index.html`

Required JSSOR JS file.
Like these:-

```
  <script src="/js/jssor.slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                OR
  <script src="/js/minified-player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now in your `component.ts` use JSSOR like this

```
    import { Component,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jssor_1_slider_init:any;
@Component({
    selector: 'ImageShow',
    template: `
        <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 900px; max-width: 95%; height: 556px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
<!-- Loading Screen -->
<div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 900px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden;">
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/1.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/2.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/3.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/3.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/4.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/4.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/5.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/5.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/6.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/6.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
<img data-u="image" src="img/7.jpg" />
<img data-u="thumb" src="img/7.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
<!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
<div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:900px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
<!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
<div data-u="prototype" class="p">
<div class="w">
<div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
</div>
<!-- Arrow Navigator -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
</div>
    `,
})
export class ImageShowComponent implements  AfterViewInit{
    constructor(){
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        jssor_1_slider_init();
    }
}
```

**Edit:-**

jssor_1_slider_init is modified function name. Download this JavaScript file <s>http://www.ravinderpayal.com/js/minified-player.js</s>  and search for the method name `jssor_1_slider_init` in this file. The code was modified by me for using multiple jssor slider in another project.

Working demo:- <s>http://www.ravinderpayal.com/dist</s>

Comment: Hi @ravinder-payal, It's userful when you have static images. I'm generating images from DataBase, then the call to `jssor_1_slider_init()` isn't working from inside ngAfterViewInit. I have tested calling `jssor_1_slider_init()` from a button, then it worked right. Heve you a glue? Thank you

Comment: You should use observables like this this. ImageService.loadImages().subscribe(images=>{this.images=image;  jssor_init() or jssor_reload() } )

Comment: Please leave an url of your page.

Comment: I see it works. Btw, jssor slider does not need minified-player.js, you can remove it.

Comment: @jssor thanks for your valuable suggestion, and I want to tell that it even works dynamically.

Comment: @jssor  I am getting this error. `Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: jssor_1_slider_init is not defined` . I followed ravi steps.

Comment: @shabbir dhangot please defne the method, and include file containing the defined method in head section.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I will  edit the answer, when I will be using SO on larger screen.

Comment: It seems the ```jssor_1_slider_init``` runs before the load of the script.

Comment: @jssor if the script is loaded in head section of html, it will be ok, but he hadn't done like this, i think. Go to the attached link in answer, and click on view page source, and check what java-script files are loaded.

Comment: @Shabbir Dhangot I checked your demo page, it works with no problem.

Comment: @RavinderPayal can you add plunkr on edit your code.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot ok brother

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I am not in state of creating plunker example, but I have edited my answer and added a missing details. For jssor add this JavaScript file, and remove the previous script inclusions for JSSOR. http://www.ravinderpayal.com/js/minified-player.js this file contains the jssor_1_slider_init method, and the JSSOR minified javascript library. So use this one.

Comment: @RavinderPayal thanx its working now after I add minified player

Comment: Yours welcome, share another working link if possible @ShabbirDhangot

Comment: will do that once I complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137198/discussion-between-shabbir-dhangot-and-ravinder-payal).