# jssor slider responsive Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, jssor

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757709/2900893) to add jssor in angular2. I have added below code of javascript into file and called in angular-cli.json.

```
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $AutoPlaySteps: 4,
          $SlideDuration: 160,
          $SlideWidth: 200,
          $SlideSpacing: 3,
          $Cols: 4,
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $Steps: 1
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
            $SpacingX: 1,
            $SpacingY: 1
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 809);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
    };
```

I observe that ScaleSlider() function is used for scale slider but its not calling.

How can I make it responsive in angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*responsive code begin*/
/*remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
function ScaleSlider() {
    var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (refSize) {
        refSize = Math.min(refSize, 809);
        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
}
ScaleSlider();
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
/*responsive code end*/
```

Comment: It should work. Please leave an url of your page here.

Comment: can you make plunkr for that.

Comment: please leave an url of your page.

Comment: Need your help. Can I have your email address ?

Comment: kindly check mail