# Jssor slider in angular 4

Tags: angular, jssor

i am trying to use jssor slider in my angular 4 project , i have already installed jssor ,but when i am trying to use in app.component.html i got error.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(17,30): error TS2552: Cannot find name '$JssorSlider$'. Did you mean 'jssor_1_slider'?
```

my code is

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   import * as $$ from 'jssor-slider';
   declare var jssor_1_slider_init: any;

  @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
     })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      title = 'client';
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: 1 };
        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", options);
      }
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        jssor_1_slider_init();
      }
    }
```

Comment: i have tried with 
import {$JssorSlider$} from 'jssor-slider';
but same error

Comment: See the question below, hope it helps,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467693/jssor-with-angular-2-typescript